# Stream connection has errored or timed out

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to set up tweepy in python but it doesn't execute the 'on_status' part. Please help me on how to solve this. I am new to this

```
import tweepy

class MyStreamListener(tweepy.Stream):
  def on_status(self, status):
      # process tweets on arrival
      print(status.text)

  def on_error(self, status_code):
      # handles streaming errors
      print(f"Encountered streaming error ({status_code})")

def main():
  consumer_key = "----"
  consumer_secret = "---"
  access_token = "---"
  access_token_secret = "---"
  
  stream = MyStreamListener(consumer_key,consumer_secret,access_token, access_token_secret)

  # filter tweets by keywords
  keywords = ['coronavirus', 'covid19', 'covid vaccine']
  stream.filter(track=keywords, stall_warnings=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Do you have elevated access to enable you to call Twitter API v1.1 (this code appears to connect to the v1.1 stream). What is the output? What version of Tweepy are you using?

Comment: I don't have elevated access. I figured it out after posting the question. I have applied for the elevated access.